# Is it possible to use JNA/JNI to access native COM/DirectX API methods?

Tags: java, winapi, directx, jna

I'm trying to call this native Windows method using JNA:

`HRESULT WINAPI DirectSoundCreate(LPGUID lpGuid, LPDIRECTSOUND* ppDS, LPUNKNOWN  pUnkOuter );`

But I'm really struggling with understanding what I should use as parameters on the Java side of things. With JNA you're supposed to create Java classes matching the native C structs, and I have done so succesfully with other parts of the WinAPI.

From what I've (I think) understood so far the LPDIRECTSOUND is a typedef to a "Long pointer to a DirectSound struct" and LPUNKNOWN is a typedef "Long pointer to an Unknown"?

I've found the native structs IDirectSound and IUnknown in DSound.h. Am I supposed to use these? I can't find a specification on what these structs contain, however, so when I try to mirror them as empty classes extending Structure on the Java side I get

> IllegalArgumentException: Structure class se.abjorklund.win32.jna.dsound.IDirectSound has unknown or zero size (ensure all fields are public)

So that obviously doesn't work. I'm guessing I'm missing something fundamental here, maybe it has something to do with the COM/Direct API that I don't understand, and answers like "go read up" are cool, as long as I can get pointers as to what to read!

Below is a working snippet of the C program I'm trying to port to Java using JNA.

`LPDIRECTSOUND directSound;
        if (directSoundCreate && SUCCEEDED(directSoundCreate(0, &directSound, 0)))`

So in C you just pass a pointer to a LPDIRECTSOUND. I guess I need to make a LPDIRECTSOUND class extending the JNA Structure class in Java? Am I close to the answer here or way off?

Comment: [The Component Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) explains the fundamentals of the system you are interfacing with.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you. I'll read it through.

Comment: There are Bridge frameworks available that allow Java code to use ActiveX/COM objects, and Java objects to be exposed to ActiveX/COM systems. However, in this case, it would probably be easier (and more efficient) to just write your DirectX code in C and use JNI/JNA to invoke that code as needed, instead of trying to access DirectX directly in Java.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks Remy, and yes, you're probably right. I've started experimenting with creating some JNI dll's and it actually doesn't seem very hard, plus I already got the DirectSound code working in the C project so it shouldn't be too much work either! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but requires some extra work in the interfaces hunting down the `Vtbl`s in the source code to map the function interfaces you need.  See the class [`WbemCli.java` in the JNA source](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Wbemcli.java) for an example of mapping a few interface classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA does support COM and there are several mappings already present in the [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.5.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/package-frame.html)  package, including the `IUnknown` interface and the corresponding `Unknown` class implementing it.

You could implement an `IDirectSound` interface (optional) or just directly implement the class by extending `Unknown`.  You will have to map the functions you need using [`_invokeNativeObject()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.5.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/COMInvoker.html#Z:Z_invokeNativeObject-int-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Class-) (or the -Int and -Void variants).

I contributed several COM classes needed to query WMI in the [WbemCli.java class](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Wbemcli.java) that can serve as examples of how to pass those parameters. (Note: I probably shouldn't have used the `I` interface prefix on the concrete classes, but it's too late now.)

Function parameters are the vtableId, an array of objects for the arguments, and a class for the return type.  To get the vtableId, you'll have to count the methods (0-indexed) in the `directSoundVtbl` struct in the header file.  I don't have a copy of the authoritative Dsound.h file, but here's [one possibility](https://github.com/gonutz/ds/blob/82969548412b9f2c00524bbd787f595e82996998/dsound_windows.go#L49) for that ordering (e.g., `CreateSoundBuffer` would have id 3).  Inheriting from `Unknown` already gets you the first 3 functions in the Vtbl (id's 0, 1, and 2).

Here's a (completely untested) example to get you started.

```
public interface DSound {

    @FieldOrder ({ "dwSize", "dwFlags", ... })
    class DSBUFFERDESC extends Structure {
        public int dwSize;
        public int dwFlags;
        // continue conventional JNA Structure mapping here
        // may have to map nested structures
    }

    class DirectSoundBuffer extends Unknown {
        // methods invoking COM similar to below
    }

    class DirectSound extends Unknown {
        public DirectSound() {
        }

        public DirectSound(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }

        public HRESULT CreateSoundBuffer(DSBUFFERDESC lpcDSBufferDesc, DirectSoundBuffer lplpDirectSoundBuffer, Unknown pUnkOuter) {
            // CreateSoundBuffer is 4th method of directSoundVtbl in Dsound.h
            return (HRESULT) _invokeNativeObject(3,
                    new Object[] { getPointer(), lpcDSBufferDesc, lplpDirectSoundBuffer, pUnkOuter }, HRESULT.class);
        }

        // Map whatever functions you need, or all of them!
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized I never thanked you for this. So, thank you! 2 1/2 years late.. :)

Comment: @habjo always fun to get random rep. :D