# Mapping a COM interface method in JNA

Tags: java, com, jna

I am trying to understand how Native.loadLibrary works, but I can not find a good explanation on the web.

I need to get access to the `IVssBackupComponents::AbortBackup` function witch is located in `VssApi.lib`. Here is a link for the function docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vsbackup/nl-vsbackup-ivssbackupcomponents

My code is like this:

```
public interface MyVssClass extends WinNT, StdCallLibrary
{
    MyVssClass INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("VssApi", MyVssClass.class);

    public int AbortBackup();
}
```

But I get *Error looking up function 'AbortBackup': The specified procedure could not be found.*  Which is obvious since I need somehow indicate that this function is in separate interface in this library.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The whole idea behind interfaces is that they don't have implementations (mostly). Why are you trying to attach a native library to one?

Comment: Ok. In this case it is doing something. Can you answer my question if the IVssBackupComponents was a class and not interface?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use JNA/JNI to access native COM/DirectX API methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61814337/is-it-possible-to-use-jna-jni-to-access-native-com-directx-api-methods)

Comment: You need to map this as a COM interface.  See my previous comment for an example of how to do so.

Comment: @DanielWiddis So what is you suggesting is to remove the "load library" line and use  _invokeNativeObject() instead?

Comment: Yes, remove the load library.  Mapping the methods is a bit more complex, requires reading the headers to find the vtbl order, but once you see the pattern it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I see that you use there the Pointer p in constructor. What it stands for? What should I assign to it when I create an object? And what is that magic number 3 stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to load the VssApi DLL is correct.  However, the `AbortBackup()` function is a function on a COM object with the `IVssBackupComponents` interface.

Mapping COM objects is a bit challenging but doable.  JNA's COM support includes a way to invoke functions on COM objects, requiring 4 bits of information:

- A pointer to the object. This is obtained from another function, either in the conventional C API exposed by the DLL or from another COM function.
- A "pointer" to the function itself. This is something called the `VtblId`.
- An array of arguments to the function. (Java primitives or objects.)
- A Java object representing the return value.

In your example, first, you have to locate the API function that will instantiate the object.  In your case that appears to be the [`CreateVssBackupComponents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vsbackup/nf-vsbackup-createvssbackupcomponents) function.  So you'll map that in your `VssApi` interface like this:

```
public interface MyVssClass extends WinNT, StdCallLibrary
{
    MyVssClass INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("VssApi", MyVssClass.class);

    HRESULT CreateVssBackupComponents(PointerByReference ppBackup);
}
```

Of note (and this is probably always the case for COM objects), that API tells you that you are responsible for releasing the object when you are done with it, so make sure to do this!

> The calling application is responsible for calling IUnknown::Release
> to release the resources held by the returned IVssBackupComponents
> when it is no longer needed.

Mapping the COM object methods can be done inheriting from the `Unknown` class in JNA's COM mappings (`class VssBackupComponents extends Unknown { ... }`) , which implements the `IUnknown` interface.  Inheriting gives you the `Release()` method, for example (you can peek inside the [`Unknown`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/cc1acdac02e4d0dda93ba01bbe3a3435b8933dab/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Unknown.java) class to see the implementation).

Unknown also exposes `_invokeNativeObject()` , `_invokeNativeInt()`, and `_invokeNativeVoid()` methods that you can map either directly or with a "wrapper" class.   Check out the [`Wbemcli.java`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Wbemcli.java) class in the JNA project for an example of a few direct and indirect mappings.  The arguments are an array of objects, the return type is straightforward with ample examples.

The hard part is finding the `VtblId` which will let JNA find the COM object's address of the actual function.

The original C header (`vsbackup.h`) for this class has a `IVssBackupComponentsVtbl` structure containing a list of functions.  The `VtblId` is the order of these functions. 0, 1, and 2 match the 3 functions in `IUnknown`.

I am unable to find a copy of `vsbackup.h` online, but I did locate [this mapping](https://tyleo.github.io/sharedlib/doc/src/winapi/vsbackup.rs.html#111) for Rust, which  isn't as authoritative as the original API, but I suspect is consistent, begins the function counting (after `IUnknown`'s 0, 1, and 2) at index 3.  The `AbortBackup()` function would then appear to be index 15.  (Please check this with another source if you can.)  So your final mapping should look something like this (completely untested):

```
class VssBackupComponents extends Unknown {

    public VssBackupComponents() {
    }

    public VssBackupComponents(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
    }

    public HRESULT AbortBackup() {
        // 16th method (MAYBE?) in IVssBackupComponentsVtbl
        return (HRESULT) this._invokeNativeObject(15,
            new Object[] { this.getPointer() }, HRESULT.class);
    }
}
```

Then in your main code, you'll call the function to get a ponter to the COM object and instantiate it as follows:

```
PointerByReference ppBackup = new PointerByReference();
MyVssClass.INSTANCE.CreateVssBackupCompontents(ppBackup);
// you should really test the HRESULT of the above line...

VssBackupComponents backup = new VssBackupComponents(ppBackup.getValue());
// You have an object now! Do stuff with it
try {
    // ... stuff ...
    backup.AbortBackup();
    // you probably want to test HRESULT
    // and do whatever else ...
} finally {
    backup.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Huge thank you for this comment! Now I understand better how this things are working. In addition I found a vsbackup.h that contains definitions in the form  const IID IID_IVssBackupComponents            =  // 665c1d5f-c218-414d-a05d-7fef5f9d5c86 
class __declspec(uuid("665c1d5f-c218-414d-a05d-7fef5f9d5c86")) IVssBackupComponents : public IUnknown
{
public:
    // get count of writer components
    STDMETHOD(GetWriterComponentsCount)
        (
        _Out_ UINT *pcComponents
        ) = 0;

  Is this somehow can help me avoiding the invokeNative calls?

Comment: Nope, that's the same header, essentially.  If you see it extending IUnknown it's a COM Object, which you can invoke functions on by index (matching the vtbl) passing the object's address (this.getPointer()), more args if required, and specifying the Java return type to cast the result to.  Once you've done a few they will seem simple!

Comment: Thank you for your help! The conversion of the headers took couple of hours. Now I am trying to run this methods and having a hard time to debug them. I get errors like invalid argument and no such a method. Can you suggest a tips how to overcome this problems?