# Debugging COM interface mapping in JNA

Tags: java, com, jna

After mapping `Vss.h` and several others headers to Java/JNA ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996150/mapping-a-com-interface-method-in-jna/63004403?noredirect=1#comment111438564_63004403)) I am trying to run some of the COM object methods and have a problem debugging them.

I do not know if I am calling the correct method or one with similar parameters. Some of the error codes I find in the JNA documentation [here](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/constant-values.html#com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinError.ERROR_NDIS_DOT11_POWER_STATE_INVALID), but it does not include all the errors I am seeing.

Some examples:

```
// gather writer metadata
public int GatherWriterMetadata(IVssAsync pAsync)
{
    return _invokeNativeInt( 5, new Object[] { getPointer(), pAsync });
}
```

I have error -2147212542

For

```
// Called to set the context for subsequent snapshot-related operations
public int SetContext(WinDef.LONG lContext)
{
    return _invokeNativeInt( 32, new Object[] { getPointer(), lContext });
}
```

I have
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)

I've tried to play with a numbers like 31,32 and 33 for the SetContext method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to "play with numbers" as you are likely to experience random behavior.

As I mentioned in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63004403/1161484) the integer `vtblId` value for the `_invokeNative...` calls has to come from the `Vtbl` structure in the header file.  I don't have direct access to the header file, but [this mapping from Rust](https://tyleo.github.io/sharedlib/doc/src/winapi/vsbackup.rs.html#111) is probably good to use, but since this interface (and all COM interfaces) extends [`IUnknown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nn-unknwn-iunknown), it already includes the functions `QueryInterface()`, `AddRef()`, and `Release()`, which take up `vtblId` [values 0, 1, and 2](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Unknown.java).

Your `GatherWriterMetadata` method, using a `vtblId` of 5, is actually invoking the `InitializeForBackup()` function, which expects a `BSTR` argument. You are giving it some other argument, so it is returning an error.  (If looking up an error by the decimal value -2147212542 doesn't work, you can translate to two's-complement hex, which in this case is `0x80042302`, a System Restore Error.)

By my count, you should be using `vtblId` of 9 for `GatherWriterMetadata`.  Please count for yourself to confirm.

Your `SetContext` method, by my count should be using `vtblId` of 35.  Again, please count the number of functions (starting at 3) to confirm this for yourself.

Also, I see you've used an int type for the return type for most of these functions rather than `HRESULT`.  Since `HRESULT` is eventually a 32-bit integer type, this will work.  However, if you actually use `HRESULT` as the return value you gain access to more convenient/self-documenting error-handling methods like `COMUtils.SUCCEEDED()` and `COMUtils.FAILED()`, or even the `COMUtils.checkRC()` method which throws a nicely formatted `COMException` on failure.

So your mappings should probably be:

```
// gather writer metadata
public HRESULT GatherWriterMetadata(IVssAsync pAsync)
{
    return _invokeNativeObject( 9,
        new Object[] { getPointer(), pAsync }, HRESULT.class);
}
```

and

```
// Called to set the context for subsequent snapshot-related operations
public HRESULT SetContext(WinDef.LONG lContext)
{
    return _invokeNativeObject( 35,
        new Object[] { getPointer(), lContext }, HRESULT.class);
}
```

Incidentally, since the Windows `LONG` type is always 32-bits, you could also simplify the second mapping to:

```
public HRESULT SetContext(int lContext) { ... }
```