# Can JNA be used for a complex Windows DLL like IMAPI

Tags: java, com, jna, com4j, imapi

I've managed to get COM4J to use some functionality in the windows IMAPI (CD writing).

However I've failed to get any of the calls that return SAFEARRAYs working, but this project doesn't appear to be currently active ...

The DLL is usually in C:\Windows\System32\imapi2.dll, and using it also requires using C:\Windows\System32\imapi2fs.dll

Looking around for a JAVA-COM bridge project that is active led me to JNA.

The remit of the project to simplify JAVA-COM bridging intrigued me .... however I fell at the first hurdle, and am hoping someone can help.

So far I've taken the Microsoft IMAPI examples and written a Powershell application, from which I have the series of calls I need to make to the API.[CDInterface][1]

The first thing you need to do with IMAPI is create an Instance of IDiskMaster2, so I've declared that via an Imapi2 interface, like so

```
public interface Imapi2 extends Library {
        Imapi2 INSTANCE = (Imapi2)
                Native.load("C:/Windows/System32/imapi2.dll" , Imapi2.class);

        public static class IDiscMaster2 extends Structure {
            int getCount;

            public int getCount() {
                return getCount;
            }
        }
        IDiscMaster2 createMsftDiscMaster2();
    }
```

Then in the main code

```
 Imapi2.IDiscMaster2 recorderList = Imapi2.INSTANCE.createMsftDiscMaster2();
        System.out.println("Found " + recorderList.getCount() + " Recorders");
```

Just putting 'imapi2' in the call to Native.load() didn't work either.

I'm guessing I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but it's not clear how you get JNA to 'see' a new dll you want to interface to ..... and also I am kind of afraid there is something very different about this API from the othe APIs that people are using JNA to talk to, so may not be worth trying!

```
public interface Imapi2 extends Library {
        Imapi2 INSTANCE = (Imapi2)
                Native.load("C:/Windows/System32/imapi2.dll" , Imapi2.class);

        public class IDiscMaster2 extends Dispatch {

            public static final CLSID CLSID_MsftDiscMaster2 = new CLSID("2735412F-7F64-5B0F-8F00-5D77AFBE261E");

            public IDiscMaster2() {
            }

            private IDiscMaster2(Pointer pvInstance) {
                super(pvInstance);
            }

            public static IDiscMaster2 create() {
                PointerByReference pbr = new PointerByReference();

                WinNT.HRESULT hres = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MsftDiscMaster2, null, WTypes.CLSCTX_ALL, null, pbr);
                if (COMUtils.FAILED(hres)) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Failed to create instance");
                    return null;
                }

                return new IDiscMaster2(pbr.getValue());
            }

            public WinNT.HRESULT _getCount(Pointer count ){
                return (WinNT.HRESULT) _invokeNativeObject(2, new Object[]{count}, WinNT.HRESULT.class);
            }

            public long getCount() {
                try {
                    long count = -1;
                    Pointer ptr = new Pointer(count);
                    WinNT.HRESULT result = _getCount(ptr);

                    COMUtils.checkRC(result);

                    return count;
                } catch ( Exception e ) {
                    System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return -1;
            }
}
```

Then invocation in main changed to

```
Imapi2 imapi2Lib = Imapi2.INSTANCE;
        Imapi2.IDiscMaster2 recorderList = new Imapi2.IDiscMaster2();

        System.out.println("Found " + recorderList.getCount() + " Recorders");
```

IntelliJ shows up uninvoked methods, so it doesn't look like create() is getting called. Not sure if this is because I need to call it, or down to the function implementing IDispatch not IUnknown.
[1]: https://github.com/nosdod/CDInterface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping a COM interface method in JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996150/mapping-a-com-interface-method-in-jna)

Comment: I think it helps me realise JNA would require me to have much more knowledge of COM internals than I have!  IDiscMaster2 implements IDisplatch which I'm guessing is in a layer above IUnkown.

Comment: I think if I could get the most basic call to work then the information you've presented in the link would begin to make sense.

Comment: It may seem overwhelming at first but there's a basic pattern to it that becomes obvious after you get a couple done.  There's some WinAPI call that gets a pointer to the COM object.   Then you map the com object and call its functions at offsets from that pointer (0, 1, 2, etc...).  It's mostly boilerplate from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996150/mapping-a-com-interface-method-in-jna) which I originally marked this as a duplicate of.  However, given the difficulty loading this, your case is unique enough that I'll attempt to give a separate answer.

The general case for COM is that there is an API function that creates the object.  You have mapped this as `createMsftDiscMaster2()`.  Note that you have allocated a resource here and it needs to be disposed of when you are done with it; the API documentation should tell you how to do that (possibly by calling `Release()` from `IUnknown`.)

Your next step is to map the `IDiscMaster2` COM class. I see two mappings here, so I'm confused as to which one you want.  The one at the top of your question is incorrect, but the one extending Dispatch later is the correct way to start, but I'm not clear where you've gone after that.  The rest of the class [should look similar to the internals](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/5ac61611f3c4a74ca3c6ed05c4ffafd7c6070e30/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Dispatch.java) of the `Dispatch` class in JNA.

In that class you can see the boilerplate that you will follow. Note that it extends `Unknown` which [follows the same boilerplate](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/5ac61611f3c4a74ca3c6ed05c4ffafd7c6070e30/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/COM/Unknown.java) for offsets 0, 1, and 2 for the first 3 COM functions `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, and `Release`.  Dispatch picks up with offsets 3, 4, 5, and 6 for COM functions `GetTypeInfoCount`, `GetTypeInfo`, `GetIDsOfNames`, and `Invoke`.

So in your mapping for `DiskMaster2` you will pick up with offset 7, and your mapping will look like:

```java
public HRESULT TheFunctionName(FOO foo, BAR bar) {
    return (HRESULT) this._invokeNativeObject(7,
            new Object[] { this.getPointer(), foo, bar },
            HRESULT.class);
}
```

This is where you need to locate the actual header file for this class to determine the order in which the functions appear in the Vtbl.  It looks like you attempted to do this with your code, but the offset 2 is already assigned in Unknown, the lowest one you'll be able to use is 7 (and continue on with 8, 9, 10 [for each function in this COM interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imapi2/nn-imapi2-idiscmaster2), in the correct order -- which you must determine from the Vtbl.)

Based on [this header](https://github.com/nihon-tc/Rtest/blob/8246e4d21323802fb84c406edc1a005991304f5a/header/Microsoft%20SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Include/imapi2.h#L879), you can see those functions mapped in order and your offsets should be: 7: get__NewEnum, 8: get_Item, 9: get_Count, and 10: get_IsSupportedEnvironment.  Use those header function mappings as a start and change them to the `_invokeNativeObject()` format above.  (They all return `HRESULT`, you'll just be changing the argument list.)

Comment: Many thanks Daniel for bearing with me … I was initially confused by the C++ in the imapi2.h. This missed out the inherited methods! Once I focussed on the C code I could totally follow how to find the offset for get_Count at 9.

Comment: Is the Native.load() call correct ? With the full path. Will try your suggestions out tomorrow with renewed confidence!

Comment: I believe the full path should work. I also don't see why just "imapi2" wouldn't work. You an also add library paths with `-Djava.library.path="add-the-path-here;${env_var:PATH}"` (or set the property in code).  Or use `NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(String libraryName, String path)`.